# How the electronic configuration of Hydrogen can explain the strength of the Hydrogen bonding?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

So, i understand that, in this case, the partial positive charge its on the Hydrogen. And that his electronic configuration is H = 1s^1
How this fact will explain the strength of the Hydrogen bonding? 
Is it because we are talking about an 1s orbital, that is much smaller, and closer to the nucleus? Or is it because the 1s orbital is electron-defficient, and, the fact that the hydrogen has a partial positive charge means that he is even more defficient on electrons. Consequently, he will "hold" this bond in a stronger way(I had a hard time on making a conclusion here). 
Help on this...

Comment: There's no simple way to tell what exactly are properties of element knowing only its configuration, and bonding depends also on its partners in bond. Much like its very difficult to tell how protein behaves only from aminoacid sequence. Complexity arises in nature from simpler things.